# Anchor tag <a> not anchor

Tags: html

I'm using an accordion for the custom WP theme. The structure of the accordion allows to show or hide a specific section if the user clicks on it:

Code:

```html
<div class="col-md-3 accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <!-- Accordion card -->
  <div class="card">

    <!-- Card header -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
        <!-- Collection card -->
        <div class="card collection-card z-depth-1-half">
          <!-- Card image -->
          <div class="view zoom">
            <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/5.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            <div class="stripe dark">
              <p>Red trousers
                <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- Card image -->
    </div>
    <!-- Collection card -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Accordion card -->
</div>
```

Section Show/Hide:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <a name="collapseOne1"></a>
  <!-- Accordion card -->
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Card body -->
    <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1" data-parent="#accordionEx">
      <div class="card-body">
        bla bla bla
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Accordion card -->
</div>
```

So far no problem. But now my problem, imagining that I have a grid like this:

```
container
row
col-md-3
```

If 4 accordions are seen perfectly in desktop, but when the navigation is mobile they are obviously superimposed.

This generates a bad user experience for me because the user has no knowledge and clicking on the first accordion below shows the show / hide in mobile but he doesn't know it. This is why I wanted to implement a simple anchor `<a>`.

```
<a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4</a>
```

and

```
<a name="C4">Chapter 4</a>
```

but in my case if i implemented

```
<a name="collapseOne1"></a>
```

I have only show and hide but not anchor, how can I have both?

Answer (score 0):

Links with "#" are refering to an id.

If you want your `<a name="collapseOne1"></a>` to also be referenced as `#C4` do this:

```html
<a href="#C4">go to Chapter 4</a>

<a id="C4" name="collapseOne1">Chapter 4</a>
```

Hope this helps!